# Update R dataframe column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to update a dataframe based on a certain condition. Here is the sample dataframe.

```
  fname mname lname
 1   RONALD D VALE
 2   RONALD  VALE
 3   JACK A SMITH
 4   JACK B SMITH
 5   JACK  SMITH
```

I would like to update the middle names column if the first and last names match. In this example, I would expect the following output.

```
  fname mname lname
 1   RONALD D VALE
 2   RONALD D VALE
 3   JACK A SMITH
 4   JACK B SMITH
 5   JACK  SMITH
```

I also do not want to update the table if there are two different middle initials. There are some missing values in the data. So the main aim is to identify and merge multiple entries which are possibly similar. At the same time, we do not want to introduce erroneous data into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(fname, lname) %>% 
  mutate(mname_count = n_distinct(mname, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(mname = ifelse(mname_count == 1, unique(na.omit(mname)), mname)) %>%
  select(-mname_count)
```

Comment: this does not update the empty middle initial to `RONALD D VALE` as in the example - I think this is because the absence of middle name is  space and not NA

Comment: Yeah, I was working off the assumption that a missing middle initial was `NA` and not `""` (which is the better coding).

Comment: using NA, can you help with another query to see how many different mnames (including NA) are present for each combination of fname and lname? I want to use this to check the query is correct or not

Comment: `df %>% 
  group_by(fname, lname) %>% 
  summarize(n_distinct(mname))`

Answer (score 0):

An ugly base R solution (assuming you changed your `""` to `NA`):

```
unic<-unique(lolz[,c("fname","lname")])

for (i in 1:nrow(unic)){
  lelz<-lolz[lolz[,"fname"]==unic[i,1] & lolz[,"lname"]==unic[i,2],]$mnam
  if (sum(!is.na(lelz))==1){
    lelz[is.na(lelz)] <- "D"
    lolz[lolz[,"fname"]==unic[i,1] & lolz[,"lname"]==unic[i,2],][,2]<-lelz
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, mname := if(uniqueN(mname[nzchar(mname)])==1) 
                           mname[nzchar(mname)] else mname, .(fname,  lname)]
df1
#    fname mname lname
#1: RONALD     D  VALE
#2: RONALD     D  VALE
#3:   JACK     A SMITH
#4:   JACK     B SMITH
#5:   JACK       SMITH
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(fname = c("RONALD", "RONALD", "JACK", "JACK", 
 "JACK"), mname = c("D", "", "A", "B", ""), lname = c("VALE", 
 "VALE", "SMITH", "SMITH", "SMITH")), .Names = c("fname", "mname", 
 "lname"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
 "4", "5"))
```